# Am I using the "obsolete" flag wrong?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I have noticed that often, when I flag a comment as obsolete, a moderator declines it, so I am wondering if I am using it wrong.

I usually flag a comment as obsolete when, for example, another comment to which the flagged comment is replying has been deleted, so the second comment does not make sense anymore.

**Example**

> Where do I find the log files?
>
> Under the same folder

If the first comment is deleted, the second one should be deleted too imo, and I would flag is as obsolete. Is this wrong?

Comment: I'd agree in that specific case. However, if there's valuable information within the comments, it should be edited into the parent post before the comments are removed.

Comment: @nhinkle anybody can do that, right? Add the info into existing answers or post a Community Wiki answer with that info.

Comment: @user1306322 sure thing. Anybody can make or suggest an edit. If you've done that, it's fine to flag the comment and note a custom reason that you edited the content into the post.